# USB Rubber Ducky Firmware Upgrade

Tags: flash, usb, firmware, badusb, hids

I just erased my firmware, using `dfu-programmer-0.7.2`:

```
$ dfu-programmer at32uc3b1256 erase
Checking memory from 0x2000 to 0x3FFFF... Not blank at 0x2001.
Erasing flash... Success
Checking memory from 0x2000 to 0x3FFFF... Empty.
```

The LED on the chip is now glowing red, instead of green.

---

I'm ready to flash it with some new firmware, using:

```
$ dfu-programmer at32uc3b1256 flash --suppress-bootloader-mem *.hex
```

However, there are several different *.hex files available online.

---

- Is `dfu-programmer-0.7.2` current / correct?
- What are the differences between the various different *.hex files?
- Which (if applicable) should I be using?

[image: Atmel Chip Erased]

Comment: This is a question for the vendor.

Comment: @schroeder i would appreciate if you could just let it ride.

Comment: Let it ride? Let what ride?

Comment: @schroeder ..The question, the post..

Comment: It's really off-topic here, and you'd get better answers from the vendor, anyway.